# 2017-01-01 00:08:57.231 format equals yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, sqldatetime

I'm a bit baffled what format these timestamps are in. I was told the format to use is `yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss` but all of the timestamps appear like this `2017-01-01 00:08:57.231`, `2017-01-01 07:43:36.348`, or `2017-01-01 13:25:55.683`. I'm not understanding why there are **four** sections to the time `?:Hour:Minute:Second` in the actual data I have when the format I'm supposed to be using only has **three** time sections. Are these datetime timestamps not actually in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is your question...

Comment: Well, there is no dot between the date and the time, and there are milliseconds after the seconds. So how coult it match the format `yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss`, which *has* a dot between date and time, and which *doesn't* have milliseconds after the seconds?

Comment: `2017-01-01 13:25:55.683` and `2017-01-01 00:08:57.231` are in the format `yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss.SSS` the trailing 3 `S`s are fractional seconds

Comment: @xtratic I still can't seem to parse the strings 2017-01-01 13:25:55.683 to a date using the format yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss.SSS.

Comment: @xtratic SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss:SSS"); formatter.parse("2017-01-01 13:25:55.683"); throws Unparseable date: "2017-01-01 13:25:55.683"

Comment: @Mr.Tea sorry, my format was botched in the first comment, since I just copied and used yours as a template. The right format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` . But please learn to read the Javadoc as @JB Nizet says, all this information is right there.

Comment: @Mr.Tea pay attention. Again, you have a dot in your pattern between the date and the time, but there is no dot in the input. And the milliseconds are separated by a dot in the input, not by a colon as in your pattern. You seem to be trying random things instead of reading the comments you got and the javadoc and applying common sense.

Comment: @JB Nizet please comment above this one.

Comment: @Mr.Tea The issue was that you originally posted `yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss` we didn't notice the `.` rather than ` ` (space) in the middle and just added the `.SSS` part.

Comment: @xtratic I see that I'm just saying the people I got this data from explicitly said it was in the format yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss and it's not.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yep, that happens quite a bit actually. Lies about formats and broken standards all over.

Comment: @Mr.Tea I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your suspicion is correct, your example date-time strings are *not* in the format `yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss`. The dot between dd and HH must be a simple mistake, it should be a space since there is a space between date and time in the timestamp strings. Furthermore all of your example strings include milliseconds: in 00:08:57.231 you’ve got 57 seconds and 231 milliseconds, or if you like, 57.231 seconds, so the last section may also be referred to as fraction of second.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String timestampString = "2017-01-01 00:08:57.231";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(timestampString, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> 2017-01-01T00:08:57.231

For the nerdily curious: It *is possible* to parse the string, or more precisely most of it, with the format you had been given, only correcting the dot into a space:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String timestampString = "2017-01-01 00:08:57.231";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.from(
            formatter.parse(timestampString, new ParsePosition(0)));
```

In this case the result comes without the milliseconds:

> 2017-01-01T00:08:57

I see no reason why you should want this, though.

### Avoid SimpleDateFormat

In a comment you gave a snippet that uses the `SimpleDateFormat` class. This class is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. I see no reason why you should want to use it. Instead I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. In my experience it is so much nicer to work with.

### Links

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`. You may especially want to study [the section *Parsing and Formatting*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html).

Answer (score -1):

These time stamps are in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ms` format, last three digits are milliseconds.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer may be short and not very well explained, but it’s at least to the point and perfectly correct.